# How can I create c# .net generic list like in Ruby?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to map features that I used from .net with Ruby

How can I create c# .net generic list like in Ruby?

```
public class ClientList : List<Client> { }
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking here. Ruby doesn't have generic types at all. (It doesn't need them, because it's dynamically typed.) What you have here is a definition of a new class that extends `List<Client>`. If all you want to do is make a `List` of `Client` objects, then you don't need to create a new type, you can just use `List<Client>` directly.

Comment: Perhaps he's looking for `List<object>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby is a very dynamic language. It does not have strong types like in C#, and therefore, it does not have (or need generics).

You can create a List in Ruby like this:

```
list = []
```

http://langref.org/ruby/lists

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
end

list = [] # create
list << A.new # add
```

Something like this? Here list is dynamic you can add any object to it.